# MSSQL Output to PHP (LAMP) not showing special chars

Tags: php, sql-server, wordpress, memcached

I am in the process of taking over our website development as we no longer need our current developers, however in the process I have to reverse engineer everything they did since there is no longer a "relationship".

The problem I am having is we do a MSSSQL pull to bring up data, and because it is a multi-lingual site (Canada EN/FR) there are of course special characters.

What I can't figure out is how they got around this. I am using the exact same SQL driver (FreeTDS), just mine is a version ahead of theirs. And UTF-8 is set where it needs to be.

The way the pull works (From what I understand) is the we build the information from the queries, then take those arrays and place them in a memcache for output. I have even used W3 Total Cache (yes, it's a wordpress site) to view all the variables being outputted and nothing stands out.

The only difference I haven't changed is they are using CGI/FastCGI as their PHP API, and I am set to Apache 2.0 Handler. Is there anything I would be missing SQL Driver-wise or anything else?

Comment: I love this bit > "as we no longer need our current developers" but you really do, otherwise you wouldn't need to come here and get help

Comment: Not really... they turned and got greedy - had no choice. And I would say I'm looking for ideas, not help :) But, thanks for the input!